# Hold all types of text on one line

Tags: html, css

**Problem:**

I am working on my personal website, but I have a problem.
I want to benefit from headings (h1 & h2) for my SEO. But when I change specific words in my lines, they just 'jump' under and above each other. How can you fix this?

**Note**

I also made an JSFiddle to make it more clear what problem I have, you can find it here:

```css
h1.small {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #787878;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

h2.small {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #787878;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

p {

    color: #787878;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hallo! Mijn naam is
<h1 class="small">***********</h1>, ik ben een <h2 class="small">***********</h2> <h2 class="small">***** developer</h2> en <h2 class="small">Grafisch *********</h2>. *****************************************************************************************
```

Comment: It's worth noting that your heading tags shouldn't be children of a `p` tag. A p tag should only contain phrasing content https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the headings (*`h1` and `h2`*) a `display:inline`. The default is `block`.

```css
h1.small {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #787878;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  
  display:inline;
}

h2.small {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #787878;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  
  display:inline;
}

p {

    color: #787878;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hallo! Mijn naam is
<h1 class="small">******************</h1>, ik ben een <h2 class="small">**********</h2> <h2 class="small">******** developer</h2> en <h2 class="small">*********** vormgever</h2>. **************************************************************** doormiddel van een goede <h2 class="small">website</h2> / <h2 class="small">webshop</h2> en een goede <h2 class="small">huisstijl</h2>. ************************************************. Na velen jaren leren kan ik <h2 class="small">websites</h2> *************************</p>
```

Comment: You should also have advised to use a block elements that can hold other blocks , div is neutral and fine here , **P is only for inline content(phrasing content)** , this brings invalid HTML ... .